# dbo.aspnet_Users table is empty where it shouldn't be

Tags: sql-server, addition, user-accounts, dbo

Why can't I see the users in this table whereas I knwon that there's users?
I can actually see them by using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
when I do a "SELECT" statement on the dbo.aspnet_users table, it comes up empty.
I'm querying as administrator then i should have all high level permissions.

Comment: How do you know that there are records in this table? Pls check in which environment you are executing query.

Comment: Someone had the same problem as me but he does not explain how he did to fix it. Apparently his table was filled too. Or maybe my table aren't filled in which case i would like to know how to do it. Using SQL script, or whatever that work fine. I'm runing windows sql server 2012 . http://forums.asp.net/p/1804111/4982561.aspx?My+dbo+aspnet_Users+table+is+empty+when+I+know+there+are+users

Comment: How do you connect with SSMS, and you do you connect with your application ?

Comment: I'm using the administrator login/password and windows authentication to connect with SSMS and i can't connect with my application. If I'm trying to connect to the Database with the Login and user I created in SSMS it works so i'm sure that the users and login were created.

Comment: Please post the code that you are using that does not work as expected.